# ebook software compatibility

Tags: installation, software-recommendation

Moving from Windows XP --  there I've used Sigil, Calibre, Pdf-viewer, and the .epub file format.

If I have authored ebooks with these in Windows -- will I be able to transfer these to Ubuntu, or will I have to reformat them?

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version? 12.04. 13.04, etc. **32-bit** or **64-bit**?

Answer (score 3):

Calibre has an Ubuntu version (from the main repository)

As does Sigil (via a PPA) : http://code.google.com/p/sigil/wiki/LinuxDistroPackages

Not sure what PDF-VIEWER is but Ubuntu has a PDF viewing application installed by default.

Comment: Ubuntu's PDF viewer is Evince, which is an excellent and efficient piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

Calibre works well, although I switched from the Software Centre (apps. library) version to the beta (from Calibre website).

I have tried Sigil, but don't remember how good it was, or how well it worked.

Ubuntu has a built-in PDF viewer, and can run Adobe Reader (for Linux). That said, Firefox now has a Java-based PDF viewer that is 'safer' and simpler to use. *What do you use the PDF-Viewer for?* (ebook viewing, PDF brochures, etc.)

Comment: Using Sigil, I normally ended doing some minor, manual adjustments to the (X)HTML code. This is something you can perfectly do from within Sigil, though, and definitely not something that _must_ be done every time you produce an e-book with it. Otherwise is fine.